# Concatenating binding data in XAML frontend with .NET maui not working

Tags: c#, xaml, concatenation, .net-maui

I am trying to add an "R" in front of my binding variable in my XAML frontend of my .NET maui project.

Below is the line of code:

```
  <Label Text="{Binding FundsTotal, StringFormat=R{0}}" Margin="0, 20, 0, 0" FontFamily="PoppinsRegular" FontSize="35" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White"></Label>
```

The String formatting works initially but as soon as I stop and start the project again, the R no longer shows up. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you test the sample in the official document about the [string format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/string-formatting)? You can try `StringFormat='R{0}'`.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code and I also lose text after reloading project.

Wrap `R{0}` with `'`.

Solution is below.

````xml
  <Label Text="{Binding FundsTotal, StringFormat='R{0}'}" Margin="0, 20, 0, 0" FontFamily="PoppinsRegular" FontSize="35" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White"></Label>```
````